# Replacing arrow function with anonymous function results in Exception

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying out the [Anuglar Heroes Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) for Typescript. While trying out the services the following code is working:

```
getHeroes() { 
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes); 
}
```

But when I change to code the following it is  not working

```
getHeroes(){
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(function (heroes:Hero[]) {
      this.heroes = heroes;
    })
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: this is null ; Zone: angular ; Task:
>   Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: this is null
>   this.heroes = heroes;

I have defined heroes inside the class as

```
heroes: Hero[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you lose the scope for `this` when you use a normal function instead of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

You can use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function:

```
getHeroes(){
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(function (heroes:Hero[]) {
      this.heroes = heroes;
    }.bind(this));
}
```

If you prefer not to use the fat arrow function.

Comment: Just to understand the basics I was playing around. This clears it

Answer (score 0):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function
>   expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own
>   this, arguments, super, or new.target). Arrow functions are always
>   anonymous. These function expression are best suited for non-method
>   functions.

So this in below function is bind to the this of the callback functoin

```
getHeroes(){
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(function (heroes:Hero[]) {
      this.heroes = heroes;
    })
}
```